# Python3 - Cxfreeze and Pandas - Error including [numpy]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, window, cx-freeze

I am having trouble compiling a Python3 for Windows 10 with PyQt and Pandas Aplication.
I create the executable via terminal with cxfreeze.

When i run my program:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Becchi-PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts__startup__.py", line 12, in 
>       **import**(name + "**init**")   File "C:\Users\Becchi-PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       exec(code, m.**dict**)   File "main.py", line 4, in    File "pag_selecao_fundos.py", line 5, in    File
>   "sugestao_portfolio.py", line 1, in    File
>   "C:\Users\Becchi-PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py",
>   line 18, in 
>       raise ImportError("Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies)) ImportError: Missing required
>   dependencies ['numpy']

I import numpy during my code and its not a problem,
The only problem is when pandas includes numpy.

Please help, I need this for work!
Thank you.